# How do I process data in Multivalued Column in Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on creating a small database in Oracle for a project at work. One of the columns will need to have multiple values recorded in it. What's the query to create a multivalued column?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you trying to store delimited items in a single column?  If so, don't -- normalize your db.

Comment: Can you precise needed use cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a user to enter multiple email addresses, I would consider creating a `USER_EMAIL` table to store such records.

```
Create Table User_Email (User_Id int, Email varchar(100));
```

User_Id would be a `foreign key` that goes back to your `USER` table.

Then you can have a 1-n number of email address per user.  This is generally the best practice for database normalization.  If your emails have different types (ie work, personal, etc.), you could have another column in that table for the type.

---

If you need to return the rows in a single column, you could then look at using `LISTAGG`:

```
select u.id,
  listagg(ue.email, ', ') within group (order by ue.email) email_addresses
from users u
  left join user_email ue on u.id = ue.user_id
group by u.id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc234/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use VARRAY columns in a Oracle column.

Look at this page: https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/VARRAY

You can see there:

1. Declaration of a type:

> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE vcarray AS VARRAY(10) OF VARCHAR2(128);

2. Declaration of a table:

> CREATE TABLE varray_table (id number, col1 vcarray);

3. Insertion:

> INSERT INTO varray_table VALUES (3, vcarray('D', 'E', 'F'));

4. Selection:

> SELECT t1.id, t2.column_value 
>   FROM varray_table t1, TABLE(t1.col1) t2 
>   WHERE t2.column_value = 'A' OR t2.column_value = 'D'